Numpy Broadcasting - Need complete understanding
I am trying to understand Numpy Broadcasting.
So I want to understand why is the below code working?
a = np.arange(4).reshape(2,2)
b = np.arange(6).reshape(3,2)

a = a[:, np.newaxis]

a + b

I mean if we try to add a and b without adding another dimension, it throws an ValueError.
"ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,2) (3,2)"
But if we when use newaxis which really adds a dimension to a, the shapes still being different, why is that working? Why NumPy is not throwing an error, for trying to perform an arithmetic operation on arrays of different dimension and shape.
Also is there a definitive resource that gives an indepth explanation of the Numpy broadcasting with an exhaustive list of examples?
After I added a dimension based off of the explanation given in the below link
How do I use np.newaxis? - kmario23's explanation Scenario 2. It seems to work. But my understanding is if the shapes are different then it should not work.

Did you read the docs? Broadcasting. Also the absolute basics for beginners § Broadcasting

and quickstart § Broadcasting rules

Related question: Numpy array broadcasting rules

Yes. I did read the docs. But its not making much of a sense. I could only uderstand the arithmetic operation involving a scalar. That is simple. But, when it goes to 2-d or 3-d its not making much of a sense.

Thanks @wjandrea. Finally figured that out reading the documentation. It took a while but now it makes sense. Thanks for re-enforcing to read the docs. I was reading them earlier, but not carefully, I guess. Thanks again. Cheers.

@wjandrea Still for me this part of the docs don't provide enough information. They show just two simple examples and how the operation is performed but they don't provide what happens in the general case. For example: x = np.random.randn(3,)and W = np.random.randn(4, 3, 3). Why W @ x != W @ np.broadcast_to(x, W.shape)? If x is broadcasted, why then the result is different?

@ado I linked three different parts of the docs. Did you read Broadcasting in the user guide? It covers multiple examples and explains the broadcasting algorithm. But also, matrix multiplication has its own broadcasting rules explained here: np.matmul() under "Notes". I can't say I understand it myself, but it looks like there are two different broadcasts happening when using a 1D and a 3D array.

@wjandrea Yep I have read the docs and that's why I mentioned this example. Moreover, in the docs it is stated: "a acts like a (5, 6) array". This is very confusing and if a user hasn't a lot of experience with numpy and broadcasting in general, he may  bump into troubles as in my example.

In [2]: a = np.arange(4).reshape(2,2)
   ...: b = np.arange(6).reshape(3,2)
   ...: 
   ...: a = a[:, np.newaxis]; a.shape
Out[2]: (2, 1, 2)

In [3]: c=a+b; c.shape
Out[3]: (2, 3, 2)

There are 2 basic rules

if number of dimensions differ, add leading size 1 dimensions as needed so they match

scale all size 1 dimensions to match; usually that means scale up, but scaling to 0 is possible


Here you explicitly added added a dimension, as the second.  So in a+b, we have a (2,1,2) and a (3,2).
By rule one the (3,2) expands to (1,3,2)
By rule two both are scaled to (2,3,2).
To further elaborate, adding a leading dimension to b does:
In [6]: b = b[None,:,:]; b.shape, b.strides
Out[6]: ((1, 3, 2), (0, 8, 4))

For comparison, the a.strides are:
In [7]: a.shape, a.strides
Out[7]: ((2, 1, 2), (8, 0, 4))

Note the 0 stride for size 1 dimension. Under the covers it's that  size 0 stride that allows it to scale the dimension.
For advanced indexing, broadcasting works the same way.
In-place limits of broadcasting
But for assignment, and += type of operations, the LHS can't be adjusted, so the application of broadcasting is slightly different.
So while a+b works, += does not:
In [8]: a+=b
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[8], line 1
----> 1 a+=b

ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (2,1,2) doesn't match the broadcast shape (2,3,2)

On the other hand c (2,3,2) is big enough to all inplace addition of either the (1,3,2) or the (2,1,2):
In [9]: c+=b

another example
In [14]: a = np.arange(4).reshape(2,2)
    ...: b = np.arange(6).reshape(3,2)
    ...: 
    ...: b = b[:, :, np.newaxis]; b.shape, b.strides
Out[14]: ((3, 2, 1), (8, 4, 0))

In [15]: c=a+b; c.shape
Out[15]: (3, 2, 2)

If we expand b to (3,2,1), in the addition a will be expanded to (1,2,2), allowing it to scale both to (3,2,2).

Why does a = a[:, np.newaxis] not change the shape from (2, 2) to (2, 2, 1)?

There is only one :.  a[:,:,np.newaxis] is needed to make a (2,2,1).  Or a[...,np.newaxis].  When indexing trailing colons are automatic, e.g. a[:, np.newaxis, :].

Oh, ok. I confused : and ....

@hpaulj - Thanks for providing this inforation about the In-place limits of broadcasting and also introducing the concept of strides.
